# AJAX call doesnt work with RESTful web service?

Tags: ajax, rest, jquery

I have a simple restful service that returns a json. I want to make an ajax call to get required data. When I try with firefox's RestClient there is no problem. Service returns the json and I can see the json on rest client. But when I use ajax call it fails. The console shows `200 OK`, but the error function executes after the call. I searched for this, commonly they say that its a cross domain problem but I fail to solve this.

This is the fail message of error function `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/myController/getInfo",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert("ERROR! \n" + JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
```

Firefox's console message

```
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Mon, 18 Feb 2013 11:51:41 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host    localhost:8080
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
```

The data returned from the call:

```
{ "date": "1 hour ago", "photoUrl": "img/movie_detail/celal.jpg", "rating": "three", "title": "Celal ile Ceren" }
```

Comment: if you get an error after a 200 response, your stringify call could be throwing the error. Need more information. Please provide a sample of the data that is confirmed to not work.

Comment: Its not matter. It still not work if I delete the stringify. Because it doesnt run the success method, it run the error func.

Comment: Can you still please provide the sample data that is confirmed to not work.

Comment: Another suggestion - try changing the ajax datatype to "text" for debugging. This will stop any automatic json parsing.

Comment: I tried text it doesnt work. And the data that I can get from rest client, but not ajax is this  

    {
       "date": "1 hour ago",
       "photoUrl": "img/movie_detail/celal.jpg",
       "rating": "three",
       "title": "Celal ile Ceren"
    }

Comment: In the url parameter you are using `http://localhost:8080/myController/getInfo`. Are you serving the web page from `http://localhost:8080/...`?

Comment: Yes I serve the page from localhost:8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are violating the [`same origin policy restriction`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX calls. You have used `http://localhost:8080/myController/getInfo` as url but this will only work if the HTML page containing this javascript was served from `http://localhost:8080/`. Otherwise the browser won't allow you to perform this AJAX call.

As a possible workaround you could modify your REST service so that it supports [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) in addition to JSON. Then you will be able to send GET requests to it (POST doesn't work with jQuery's JSONP implementation because it is using a `<script>` tag).

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. But darin I will also need POST so I wthink JSONP is not an usable way for me. Is there any different way to solve this?

Comment: Another possibility is to use [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) but the client browser that you are using needs to support it. The idea is that you will need to modify your REST API so that it sets some special response HTTP headers. If the client browser doesn't support it your only chance is to build a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then send the AJAX request to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CORS for this purpose.

Example code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 

function CrosDom_ajax(url) {
        if (window.XDomainRequest
        && $.browser.msie
        && $.browser.version < 10) {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
               alert(xdr.responseText);

            };
            xdr.open("get", url);
            xdr.send();
        }
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (response) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
         }
    }
```

Also you need to Write the following code in server side, to allow cross domain access

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```